# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Google Docs for accepting the suggestion showed in the autocorreptor popup?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-docs

I want to use only keyboard so I wonder if there is a keyboard shortcut in Google Docs for accepting the suggestion showed in the autocorreptor popup.

Comment: The Google Docs help menu has option that shows the built-in shortcuts. If you need further help please show what you have tried and a dd a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Found it on the help menu, it's  <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>  on Mac (<kbd>F10</kbd> instead of <kbd>\</kbd>  on others, I think)